# The name html doesn't exist in the current context on MVC View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

HI I have a view that is created from the Controllder Method.

Now I am writing the HTML View Code on this Page.

Somehow I am not getting any html controls on this page.
When i type the below line, it says "The name html doesn't exist in the current context" 
Ex: <%= Html.TextBox

Any Clue why i am not getting html tags.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing your `Inherits` attribute in your `Page` declaration at the top of the view?

It should look like this (if it is strongly-typed):

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNamespace.Models.MyViewModel>"
```

or like this (if it is not strongly-typed):

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"
```

I find that if I remove this declaration from my view, the Html object will no longer intellisense.

Comment: It is not strongly-typed. I also added Inherits = "System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<DataModel.Employees>>".

Comment: It is working now... Earlier it has some user controls code. After i have cleaned, it is working fine. Thanks Rob.